# How to use ngRepeat on custom directive with transclusion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm trying to get the following piece code working (angular 1.4.3, jquery 2.1.4, chrome 45):

```
<mec-row ng-repeat="row in [{id:'row1',val:'val1'},{id:'row2',val:'val2'}]">
    <cell>{{$index}}</cell><cell>{{row.id}}</cell><cell>{{row.val}}</cell>
</mec-row>
```

The template (row.tmpl) for the directive:

```
<section>
  <div>
    <div class="checkbox">checkbox</div>
    <div class="rows-placeholder"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

So the idea is that we're going to have the rows replaced by the <section> part. Furthermore, I want .rows-placeholder be replaced by whatever is inside the mec-row. And all this with the following directive:

```
(function(ng,$) {
  'use strict';

  ng.module('table').directive( 'mecRow', RowDirective );

  function RowDirective() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'row.tmpl',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: link,
      transclude: true
    };

   function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      $(element).find('.rows-placeholder').replaceWith(transclude());
    }
  }
})(angular,jQuery);
```

This doesn't give me the expected result (only the last item in the array is put in):

```
<!-- ngRepeat: row in [{id:'row1',val:'val1'},{id:'row2',val:'val2'}] -->
<mec-row ng-repeat="row in [{id:'row1',val:'val1'},{id:'row2',val:'val2'}]" class="ng-scope">
  <section>
    <div>
      <div class="checkbox">checkbox</div>

    </div>
  </section>
</mec-row>
<!-- end ngRepeat: row in [{id:'row1',val:'val1'},{id:'row2',val:'val2'}] -->
<mec-row ng-repeat="row in [{id:'row1',val:'val1'},{id:'row2',val:'val2'}]" class="ng-scope">
  <section>
    <div>
      <div class="checkbox">checkbox</div>    
      <cell class="ng-binding ng-scope">1</cell><cell class="ng-binding ng-scope">row2</cell><cell class="ng-binding ng-scope">val2</cell>    
    </div>
  </section>
</mec-row>
<!-- end ngRepeat: row in [{id:'row1',val:'val1'},{id:'row2',val:'val2'}] -->
```

Finally I want to get rid of the cell tag and replace it simply by a div. If I add this piece of code to the link function:

```
$('cell', $(element)).replaceWith(function(){
  return $("<div />").append($(this).contents());
});
```

... it just ends up even more painful. Console error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'nodeValue' of undefined
```

However, now only the first item in the array gets parsed.

I'm not quite sure what's happening, and how to fix this. Hope you can help.